# On click echo attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a gallery that uses PHP to go through asset folders and serve as sort of an album system. The code below retrieves files as albums :

```
<?php
include_once("../PhpScript/RetAlbInfo.php"); 
$files = array_slice(scandir('../Assets/Gallery/'), 2);
for($albflcnt = 0;$albflcnt<count($files);$albflcnt++){
    echo "<div style='...'><div class='albm' style='...' onmousedown='gotoalbum();albnm();'></div><p style='...'>".$files[$albflcnt]."</p></div>";
}
?>
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to get folder names from each `<p>` tag and append it to the url so it would show it's sub folder.

Comment: Readability wise: Do not use `style` unless no other option (classes are cooler). Use `foreach` instead of `for` loop. Variable names could be more descriptive, `albflcnt` doesn't tell much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with GLOB_ONLYDIR option

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
    $dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
    print_r( $dirs);

 ?>
```

Comment: hi I'm sorry i forgot to mention that i need to get them on click and the value i want to retrieve is the one i clicked on

Answer (score 0):

You might be wanting a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)? Not 100% sure. Here is a basic example. There are portions that may or may not be relevant. This basically builds a bread crumb system of sorts, but there may be parts you are looking for:

```
<?php
# Create some defines in the root of the website if not already done
# This is your url
define('SITE_URL','http://www.example.com');
# This is the root path
define('BASE_DIR',__DIR__);
# This is where everyour files are stored
define('MEDIA_DIR',__DIR__.'/media/');

/*
**  @description    This is just a link builder, there may be some functionality you could use here
**  @param  $path   [string] Relative path
**  @param  $pathStr    [string] Absolute path
**  @param  $append [string | empty]    This is just append to whatever page processes this script
*/
function createLinks($path,$pathStr,$append = '/index.php')
    {
        # Used for the link
        $url    =   SITE_URL.$append;
        # Explodes relative path
        $arr    =   array_filter(explode('/',$path));
        # Loop through to create break crumb
        foreach($arr as $dir) {
            $pathStr    .=  '/'.$dir;
            $new[]      =   '<a href="'.$url.'?goto='.urlencode(base64_encode($pathStr)).'">/'.$dir.'</a>';
        }
        # Return final bread crumb
        return implode('',$new);
    }

# Decodes the path name, you should probably do a more secure encryption / decription method
function getPathFromRequest($path)
    {
        return base64_decode(urldecode($path));
    }
# Set base absolute path
$core   =   MEDIA_DIR;
# Process the absolute path
if(!empty($_GET['goto'])) {
    $base   =   str_replace('//','/',getPathFromRequest($_GET['goto']));
    if(is_dir($base))
        $base   =   $base.'/';
}
else
    $base   =   $core;

# If is a directory, recurse and show the bread crumbs
if(is_dir($base)){
    $skip   =   RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS;
    $sFirst =   RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST;
    $dir    =   new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($base,$skip),$sFirst);
    # Loop through the file paths
    foreach($dir as $file) {
        $fname  =   $file->__toString();
        if(is_file($fname)) {
            $abs        =   str_replace($base,'',$fname);
            $useType    =   (!empty($_GET['goto']))? $base : $core;
            echo createLinks($abs,$useType).'<br />';
        }
    }
}
else {
    # Redirect to file if is a file
    if(is_file($base)) {
        header('Location: '.SITE_URL.'/'.str_replace(BASE_DIR,'',$base));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Base view in the browser gives you something like *(this is just from a directory I have)*:

```
/css/form.css
/css/styles.css
/images/bkg/bkg_white.png
/images/bkg/row_grad01.png
```

Then html source would look like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWV%3aaazcw%3D%3D">/css</a><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWV%3aaazcy9mb3JtLmNzcw%3D%3D">/form.css</a><br />
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWV%3aaazcw%3D%3D">/css</a><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWV%3aaazcy9zdHlsZXMuY3Nz">/styles.css</a><br />
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWVkaWEvL2ltYWdlcw%3D%3D">/images</a><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWVkaWEvL2ltYWdlcy9ia2c%3D">/bkg</a><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWVkaWEvL2ltYWdlcy9ia2cvYmtnX3doaXRlLnBuZw%3D%3D">/bkg_white.png</a><br />
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWVkaWEvL2ltYWdlcw%3D%3D">/images</a><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWVkaWEvL2ltYWdlcy9ia2c%3D">/bkg</a><a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?goto=L2Rh%123BB%bi123abBAjMyMC91c2dyLzMwMzAwNjc1aHR321BaBaaXRlc3QvbWVkaWEvL2ltYWdlcy9ia2cvcm93X2dyYWQwMS5wbmc%3D">/row_grad01.png</a><br />
```

If you were to click the `bkg` in the 3rd or 4th link, it would display:

```
/bkg_white.png
/row_grad01.png
```

Clicking one of those would open the file in the browser. Anyway, you might be interested in some of this, all of it, or none of it! It's hard to guess with out seeing what you currently have vs what you are trying to achieve.